# Inclusion of header causes requests to not be send

Tags: javascript, routes, superagent

I have react application where I want to add a request-id header to my requests, such that the frontend can tell the backend to undo a specific request. So requests (using superagent) are something like this:

```
let result = request(method, endpoint);

result = result.set("Accept", "application/json").set("Request-Id", getRequestId());
```

And when I add the ".set("Request-Id", getRequestId())" I get the error below.
[image: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Request has been terminated Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.]

I can see that I can send requests with postman with the request-ID header and I can see that the loadbalancer does not receive any requests other than options calls. CORS is enabled and exposing all headers for all origins.

Does anybody have ideas for what might be wrong? I'm quite new to frontend development.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I was that my corporate computer that has hardcoded in restrictions in the browser for not allowing custom headers. So I went in and found a standard header that in conjunction with the url could be used for the id so https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date in my case.

Another evidence for this is that I could make post anything on my corporate computer on Facebook. Since the Facebook application uses custom headers.